# Issue with ol.sourceXYZ and custom projection

Tags: openlayers

i have a problem with EPSG:4269 projection. I'm working with OL v4.6.4. I register the new projection: proj4.defs("EPSG:4269","+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs"); and add it to OL projections. I try to create a ol.layer.Tile with source ol.source.XYZ but when i try to load it to map (with projection EPSG:4269) i don't see the tile. It seem that the problem is related to missing extent of the custom projection. The code was developed by another person and i found a strange constant const GENERIC_GRID_EXTENT = [0,0,8388608,8388608]; that is used in case of missing projection extent. This work with (and i need to understand why) with custom projection as EPSG:3003 from example with layer in the same projection and with source XYZ. Anyone can help me ? i try to set the boudary extent provided https://epsg.io/4269 but it doesn't work. Thanks Francesco

Comment: EPSG:4269 is a lon/lat projection similar to EPSG:4326 with an extent of [-90, -180, 90, 180].  Also because the width is twice the height the source is unlikely to use a standard XYZ tile grid and you will need to set up either a custom tile grid or custom tileUrlFunction similar to https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/xyz-esri-4326-512.html (but not all services use the same method as esri, so providing the url of your source in the question would be useful).

Comment: Thanks Mike, i use tilecache service. Any Idea? Thanks